# Explain example in Elkies's ABC Conjecture paper

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, polynomials, riemann-surfaces

The reference: [The ABC's of Number Theory (PDF)](https://dash.harvard.edu/bitstream/handle/1/2793857/Elkies%20-%20ABCs%20of%20Number%20Theory.pdf?sequence=2)

On page 17 of the PDF, or 72 of the scan, he solves a Putnam problem.

In the solution he uses a special case of Mason's theorem, for $F$ a polynomial, and gets the inequality:

$\text{deg}(P') = m-1 \geq 2m -r-s$

Can you explain how to derive this from the statement of Mason's theorem above, and specifically some intuition on what is $F^{-1}(\{0,1,\infty\})$, in relation to $F$ and how it counts roots, discarding multiplicity?

Comment: Also, on page 16 of the PDF he writes:
"more succinctly, $V_{D}(A)$ is the number of solutions to $F(t) = 0$ in $CP^1$. can you explain why?